# Auto complete for a variable inside a foreach

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, foreach, phpdoc

I have the following code:

```
class Orders{
    /**
     *
     * @var Supplier
     */
    private $suppliers; //Array of Supplier

    function loopAllSuppliers(){
        foreach($this->suppliers as $supplier){
            $supplier->/*no suggestion*/ //Can't get the method's to show here

            $this->suppliers->getSupplierName(); //methods in class Supplier show normally here
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is easy. I just want to be able to declare a type for my variable `$supplier` like how I did it with `$suppliers`.

Notes:

- Supplier is a class which has a  public method getSupplierName().
- I'm using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: If your `$suppliers` is an array of `Supplier`, then your phpDoc annotation is wrong. In other IDEs you can annotate such an array as `@var Supplier[]`, have you tried that?

Comment: @DCoder yes `$suppliers` is an array of `Supplier` and I tried `@var Supplier[]`, but it doesn't work. Actually changing it to `@var Supplier[]` made no suggestions appear for `$this->suppliers->`

Comment: Well, if it's an array, it doesn't actually have any methods, does it?

Comment: hmmmm it seems the solution is to find the annotation for declaring a variable as an array of objects in Netbeans. Can't find the syntax for it though.

Comment: The proper annotation/tag syntax here is indeed "var Supplier[]".  This will be standardized soon, and IDEs will probably begin to add autocompletion based on seeing this syntax sometime after it is standardized.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
class Orders{
    /**
     *
     * @var Supplier
     */
    private $suppliers;

    function loopAllSuppliers(){
        foreach($this->suppliers as $supplier){ /* @var $supplier Supplier */
      //Must declare the type again inside the foreach as Netbeans doesn't support
      // defining variable as arrays in doc blocks, yet.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `foreach($this->suppliers as /* @var Supplier */ $supplier)`

Comment: You can define vars as arrays in netbeans: /** @var Supplier[] */

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
class Orders
{
    /**
     * @var Supplier[]
     */
    private $suppliers;

    public function loopAllSuppliers()
    {
        foreach($this->suppliers as $supplier) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me this not work:

```
foreach ($suppliers as /* @var $supplier Supplier */ $supplier) {
    $supplier->/*should have suggestions*/
}
```

my solution:

```
foreach ($suppliers as $supplier) {
    if($suppliers instancof Supplier) {
        $supplier->
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this if $this->suppliers is an array:

```
function loopAllSuppliers(){
    foreach($this->suppliers as $key => $supplier){
        $supplier->/*no suggestion*/ //Can't get the method's to show here

        $this->suppliers[$key]->getSupplierName(); //should work

        $this->suppliers->getSupplierName(); //methods in class Supplier show normally here
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution I'm still accessing the `$this->suppliers` to get the methods. What I'm trying is to access the methods of `$supplier`.

Comment: that is the same. If you loop thru an array of elements, you can access the methods of an element on either way.
Maybe, you could provide us a working example that does not behave the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this(in netbeans) by doing the following:

> ```
>     foreach ($suppliers as /* @var $supplier Supplier */ $supplier) {
>         $supplier->/*should have suggestions*/
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

With PHP7 and PHPStorm I can use:

```
use path/to/Supplier; //needs the path for your class Supplier

foreach ($suppliers as /* @var $supplier Supplier */ $supplier) {
    echo $supplier->getName(); //Output each Name
}
```